# How to test a bit in a decimal number

Tags: vb.net, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have a set of decimal numbers. I need to check if a specific bit is set in each of them. If the bit is set, I need to return 1, otherwise return 0.
I am looking for a simple and fast way to do that.
Say, for example, I am checking if the third bit is set. I can do (number AND (2^2)), it will return 4 if the bit is set, otherwise it will return 0. How do I make it to return 1 instead of 4?
Thank you!

Comment: How are these "decimal numbers" stored? More than likely you have a collection of integers, which are actually stored in binary, not decimal.

Comment: Hi, Keith. No, I have an array of integers. I do not know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((number AND (2^bitnumber) <> 0) then return 1 else return 0 end if
```

If you can change your return type to boolean then this is more elegant

```
return ((number AND (2^bitnumber)) <> 0)
```

Comment: Hi, Richard! Thanks for the help. No, this has to be used in an expression. I need to multiply one number by a result of the bit test function. And the faster the function runs, the better, cos there are a LOT of numbers :-)

Answer (score 1):

While the division solution is a simple one, I would think a bit-shift operation would be more efficient. You'd have to test it to be sure, though.  For instance, if you are using 1 based bit indexes, you could do this:

```
Dim oneOrZero As Integer = (k And 2 ^ (n - 1)) >> (n - 1)
```

(Where k is the number and n is the bit index).  Of, if you are using 0 based bit indexes, you could just do this:

```
Dim oneOrZero As Integer = (k And 2 ^ n) >> n
```

Comment: Hi, Steven! Thanks for the help. An interesting solution. I will test it and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if it can help anyone more than the above, but, here we go.

When I need to fast check a bit in number I compare the decimal-value of this bit directly.

I mean, if I would need to see of the 6th bit is on (32), I check its decimal value, like this:

```
if x and 32 = 32 then "the bit is ON"
```

Try for instance check 38 with 32, 4 and 2...  and the other bits.
You will see only the actual bits turned on.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys, I am too slow today.
To test a bit number "n" in a decimal number "k":
(k AND 2^(n-1))/(2^(n-1))
will return 1 if the bit is set, otherwise will return 0.

=====================================================
Hi again, guys!
I compared the performance of the three proposed solutions with zero-based indexes, and here are the results: 
"bit-shift solution" - 8.31 seconds 
"if...then solution" - 8.44 seconds 
"division solution" - 9.41 seconds 
The times are average of the four consecutive runs. 
Surprisingly for me, the second solution outperformed the third one. 
However, after I modified the "division solution" this way: 
p = 2 ^ n : oneOrZero = (k And p) / p 
it started to run in 7.48 seconds. 
So, this is the fastest of the proposed solutions (despite of what Keith says :-). 
Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: Division is overkill; you want to test whether `k AND 2^(n-1)` is non-zero. And in what sense is `k` "decimal"?

Comment: K is decimal like, say, a number 6548469361 is decimal. Is division slower than "if...then"?

Comment: Integers are (almost certainly) stored in binary, not decimal. You're thinking of them as "decimal numbers" because that's how they're represented in source code, but they're not decimal at all -- and since you're examining bits, it's an important distinction.

Comment: Division tends to be slower than most other operations (though in this case the compiler *might* optimize it to a bitwise shift). A `<> 0` test is likely to be more efficient. It's also a much clearer expression (to a human reader) of what you're doing. (In C-like languages, you likely wouldn't even need to do the comparison; all non-zero values are treated as true; I *think* the same applies to VB. So you should be able to write `if k AND 2^(n-1) then ...`

Comment: Hi, Keith! if k AND 2^(n-1) then ... works in VB as well, as it turned out. Does not improve the performance, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Simply use a bit mask.  I enumerate the bits, then AND the number with the bit value.  Very little math on the PC side as it uses lookup tables instead.  The AND basically shuts off all the other bits except the one you are interested in.  Then you check it against itself to see if it's on/off.

```
Enum validate
    bit1 = 1
    bit2 = 2
    bit3 = 4
    bit4 = 8
    bit5 = 16
    bit6 = 32
    bit7 = 64
    bit8 = 128
End Enum

If num And validate.bit3 = validate.bit3 Then true
```